# Defining function call dynamically with javascript to anchor tag

Tags: javascript

I have an anchor tag with `id=1` and I am trying to define `onClick="menu_function(shopname)"` using the logic below, but it's not working like `a.href`:

```
function display_details(shopname,img)
{
    var a = document.getElementById("1");
    a.href = "./menu.php";
    a.onClick ="menu_function(shopname)";
}
```

Can you tell my why is it not working and guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function expression as the value for `onclick`, not a string:

```
 function display_details(shopname,img)
 {
     var a = document.getElementById("1");
     a.href = "./menu.php";
     a.onclick = function(){
        menu_function(shopname);
     };
 }
```

Also note: JavaScript is case sensitive and the event is called `onclick` (lowercase) not `onClick`.